# ul/li on top right of page blocking logo and other elements from rising to top left of page

Tags: html, css

I have a menu on the top right of my page, and a logo on the top left. The logo is being held down however, from rising to the very top left, by the menu.

If I get rid of the menu the logo can move freely anywhere I want it, but for now trying to adjust with margin-bottom isn't working. The logo is blocked from moving upwards. Probably a very simple answer but I'm stumped.

Any help appreciated.

Ok posting the code here:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1024px;
}

#header {}

#headerbar {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Gill sans;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  color: #999b9d;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#menu {
  margin-left: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999b9d;
}

#menu a:visited {}

li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Gill Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Gill sans;
  color: #7a4470;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  float: left;
}


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">



<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="headerbar"><h2>Burnet design</h2><img src="file:///Macintosh      HD/Users/poste2/Desktop/Casey/website 2016/images/logoburnet.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<h1>My name is Casey Burnet and I am a <br /> Graphic Designer living   and working in <br /> Montreal.</h1>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide example what your HTML and CSS look like.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should first read over [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then post some code otherwise it's difficult to help you

Comment: how do I post the code?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should practise with floats in a clean css and html file. But with the information you are now giving I can't help you, you need to upload more code, especialy from the html file.

The link below is how to add text as code in your question:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

And this link is a link to some explaining of floats in css files:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks to tell me, i'm quite new so I shall delete this answer